# Shell script to find the process state while excluding 'ps grep command'

Tags: linux, bash, shell

can someone guide me writing shell script to find if the process is active or not? I have to exclude my own grep process filtering from ps command. I want to pass the process as a parameter,

script: (this is currently catching my own process)

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE=$1
echo $1
if ps ax | grep $SERVICE  > /dev/null
then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

example input tried: (though the process is dead I'm getting status as "ok")

```
./processchecker.sh '/usr/sbin/mysqld'
./processchecker.sh '[/usr/sbin/]mysqld' (i tried using square brackets using online suggestions but failed)
```

Please help.

Comment: I added an answer then realized both my example and your example work well in my small test case. If you add a 'grep -v processchecker' after the ps does it solve the problem? It is possible that your grep statement is running and finding itself in the process tree. Can you remove the > /dev/null and post the output?

Comment: awesome, it worked. appreciate your help. Thank you :)

Comment: The square brackets match exactly one character. The regex `[/usr/sbin]` matches `/` (which is needlessly enumerated twice), or `u`, or `s`, or `r`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is close, but you want to save the status of the `grep` command (via `$?`) and then if/else off of that value.

```
#!/bin/sh
SERVICE=$1
echo $1
ps ax | grep $SERVICE | grep -v ${0} > /dev/null
status=${?}

if [ "${status}" = "0" ]; then
    echo "ok"
else
    echo "not ok"
fi
```

Comment: Downvote - the advice to explicitly examine `$?` instead of the OP's basically correct and idiomatic code is a disservice. The `grep -v` part nominally solves the OP's problem, but the rest is poor guidance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pgrep` as well - which is a little more efficient:

```
#!/bin/sh

service=$1
status=0
if [ ! -z "$service" ]; then
  pgrep "$service" >/dev/null; status=$?
  if [ "$status" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ok"
  else
    echo "not ok"
  fi
fi

exit "$status"
```

It's better to have an appropriate exit value as well.